# android dialog- how to findViewById of my item

Tags: android, android-layout, android-dialog

My TextView can get message of this dialog as follow:

```
AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
builder.setMessage("your message");
AlertDialog dialog = builder.show();
TextView messageText = (TextView)dialog.findViewById(android.R.id.message);
```

but, how can I get these string item to TextView ???

```
final CharSequence[] items = { "String 1", "String 2", "String 3" };
AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
builder.setItems(items,new DialogInterface.OnClickListener(....
AlertDialog dialog = builder.show();
TextView item = (TextView)dialog.findViewById(android.R.id.?);
```

please help me~~

Comment: you can get the selected item via the supplied listener

Comment: there will be 3 items with the same id ... prolly `android.R.id.text1` ... the main question is why you need this ...

Answer (score 1):

These are list items, not TextViews. You will get the selected item in the callback for the `setItems` method as such

```
builder.setItems(items, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener()
    @Override
    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
        String chosen = items[which].toString();
    }
});
```